# Not able to create a 3x3 grid of subplots to visualize 9 Series individually

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I want to have a 3x3 grid of subplots to visualize each Series individually.
I first created some toy data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style='whitegrid', rc={"figure.figsize":(14,6)})

rs = np.random.RandomState(444)
dates = pd.date_range(start="2009-01-01", end='2019-12-31', freq='1D')
values = rs.randn(4017,12).cumsum(axis=0)
data = pd.DataFrame(values, dates, columns =['a','b','c','d','e','f','h','i','j','k','l','m'])
```

Here is the first code I wrote:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
for col in n_cols:
    ax = data[col].plot()
```

With these lines of code the problem is that I get the 3x3 grid but all the columns have been plotten on the same subplotsAxes, in the bottom right corner.
[Bottom Right Corner with all Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ppl6j.png)

Here is the second thing I tried:

```
n_cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'j']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
for col in n_cols:
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            ax[i,j].plot(data[col])
```

But now I get all the columns plotted on every single subplotAxes.
[All AxesSubplot with same lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFVVk.png)

And if I try something like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(sharex=True, sharey=True)
for col in n_cols:
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            ax[i,j].add_subplot(data[col])
```

But I get:
TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable

I am sorry but can't figure out what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you're plotting each series in each of the subplots:

```python
for col in n_cols:
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            ax[i,j].plot(data[col])
```

Following your example code, here is a way to only plot a single series per subplot:

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rs = np.random.RandomState(444)
dates = pd.date_range(start="2009-01-01", end='2019-12-31', freq='1D')
values = rs.randn(4017,12).cumsum(axis=0)
data = pd.DataFrame(values, dates, columns =['a','b','c','d','e','f','h','i','j','k','l','m'])

n_cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'j']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True)

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        col_name = n_cols[i*3+j]
        ax[i,j].plot(data[col_name])

plt.show()
```