# How to create multiple scatterplots with a single data point in them in python?

Tags: python, scatter-plot

I have been trying this code to create multiple scatterplots with a single point but it plots three points in one figure. How to create nine figures with only one data point?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

h=[[0,2,5,7],[0,4,15,11],[0,8,25,13]]
g=it.combinations([1,3,2],2)
k=[]
for i in list(g):
     k.append(list(i))
print(k)
for j in range(3):
     plt.subplot(3,3, j+1)
     for n in k:
         plt.scatter(h[j][n[0]],h[j][n[1]])
     j=j+1
```

[This is the output. But how to make it nine figures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDiWA.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to create a 3x3 grid of subplots to visualize 9 Series individually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59512068/not-able-to-create-a-3x3-grid-of-subplots-to-visualize-9-series-individually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import itertools as it
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

h=[[0,2,5,7],[0,4,15,11],[0,8,25,13]]
g=it.combinations([1,3,2],2)
k=[]
for i in list(g):
     k.append(list(i))
print(k)

fig,axs=plt.subplots(3,3)
for j in range(3):
     for i,n in enumerate(k):
         axs[j][i].scatter(h[j][n[0]],h[j][n[1]])
     j=j+1
plt.show()
```